# Static linking error when compiling myGame in Cocos2d-x v3.6

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-win32

I'm using `Cocos2d-x v3.6` for win32 desktop, `Visual studio 2013` and C++.

There are many errors appeared When compiling my project, and these errors because of the linker unable to linking between my project and cocos2d-x library files `.lib`, although I have set all settings correctly.

[image]
The picture in its large size: [Show me](http://i.cubeupload.com/RAzXe0.jpg).

Firstly, the following is the folder that has the library `.lib` files:

[image]

Secondly, the visual studio settings that I added:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Now, What is the reason behind these errors.**

Comment: Almost 700MB for that lib file seems abnormally large. (mine is < 6MB). Did you change the Cocos2d-x project to produce a static library?

Comment: @KompjoeFriek: Yes, I have changed to static `.lib`. and the size that you are mentioned If the library is dynamic version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `dllimport` and `dllexport` parts.
See `cocos\platform\win32\CCPlatformDefine-win32.h`:

```cpp
#if defined(CC_STATIC)
    #define CC_DLL
#else
#if defined(_USRDLL)
    #define CC_DLL     __declspec(dllexport)
#else         /* use a DLL library */
    #define CC_DLL     __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#endif
```

To do that, just add `CC_STATIC` to the preprocessor definitions of your cocos2d-x library project, and the project linking with it.

Comment: Oh my God, finally the problem was solved and now everything is alright.
Thank you very much.